Can I recover a joomla site with an older database
I lost my database.  I have a backup copy from March but it's a different name.  I've changed the settings in configuration.php and uploaded the older copy to my server but I'm not getting any results.
Also have a complete site backup and a complete database backup but I don't think the passwords are working.
I'm assuming the Akeeba Backup is asking for database password and user but I do not think I have that info.

This isn't a coding question. See the [help] and try https://joomla.stackexchange.com or the Joomla support forum.

When you restore old db backup, did you double check following variables in configuration.php?
$db = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';

